# Выбрать selected после POST

Tags: php

```
<form action="<?=base_url();?>cms/getCategoryByLang" method="POST">

    <select name="language" onchange="this.form.submit()">

        <?php foreach($language as $lang):?>

        <option value=<?=$lang[ 'language']?>>
            <?=$lang[ 'language']?>
        </option>

        <?php endforeach?>

    </select>

</form>
```

Выбранное значение отправляется в контроллер, где возвращает `category by language` и т.к. это все без ajaxa, страница перезагружается и выводится последнее значение `$lang['language']`, а не выбранное.

Как сделать так, чтобы выводил не последнее значение, а выбранное?

Comment: А выбранное значение в какой переменной хранится?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский `$_POST['language']` же

Comment: Нет, но выбранное значение приходит в другом массиве $category['language']

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Это просто массив языков для `select`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а, я думал ему надо после выбора, выделять, тот что был выбран. Ответ с низу в принципе имеет верную логику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form action="<?=base_url();?>cms/getCategoryByLang" method="POST">

    <select name="language" onchange="this.form.submit()">

        <?php foreach($language as $lang):?>
            <option value=<?=$lang['language']?> <?=($category['language']==$lang['language'])?'selected':''?>><?=$lang['language']?></option>
        <?php endforeach?>

    </select>

</form>
```